# PHP post request, receiving always null value

Tags: php, server, request, postman

I'm experimenting with some PHP code, not so expert...
I'm a beginner in PHP so please forgive me.

I wrote this simple code:

```
<?php
echo("test");
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") {
    $name = $_POST['fname'];
    if (empty($name)) {
      echo "Name is empty";
      var_dump($name);
    } else {
      echo $name;
    }
} else {
    echo("IS A GET");
}
?>
```

i'am using postman to send a POST request but looks like the parm I send Is always NULL.

is it something wrong on my code?

[image: postman]
thanks

Comment: Always first test if the POST value is available, before assigning it to some variable. If `$_POST['fname']` not exists, your script will have an error at `$name = $_POST['fname']`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your PostMan request is wrong. You've added your field as a query parameter. Instead switch to the 'Body' tab, select `form-data` and add your field there.

[image]